# FreeSWITCH may not be responding to requests on port 8021

Tags: freeswitch, bigbluebutton

- I'm getting below error while restarting the BigBlueButton server:

```
Starting BigBlueButton
Job for freeswitch.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status freeswitch.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

# Potential problems described below
grep: /opt/freeswitch/var/log/freeswitch/freeswitch.log: No such file or directory

#
# Error: Unable to connect to the FreeSWITCH Event Socket Layer on port 8021
#
```

- First, I thought the DB files for freeswitch got corrupted so performed below setps to resolve it (As mentioned in BBB docs):

```
$ sudo systemctl stop freeswitch 
$ rm -rf /opt/freeswitch/var/lib/freeswitch/db/* 
$ sudo systemctl start freeswitch
```

- But FreeSWITCH is not creating the new DB files on startup.
- The output of `**$/opt/freeswitch/bin# ./freeswitch**` is as per below:

```
2022-11-16 09:57:10.825148 0.00% [INFO] switch_event.c:713 Activate Eventing Engine.
2022-11-16 09:57:10.835584 0.00% [WARNING] switch_event.c:683 Create additional event dispatch thread 0
2022-11-16 09:57:10.861618 0.00% [INFO] switch_nat.c:417 Scanning for NAT
2022-11-16 09:57:10.861776 0.00% [DEBUG] switch_nat.c:170 Checking for PMP 1/5
2022-11-16 09:57:11.861899 0.00% [DEBUG] switch_nat.c:170 Checking for PMP 2/5
2022-11-16 09:57:12.862066 0.00% [DEBUG] switch_nat.c:170 Checking for PMP 3/5
2022-11-16 09:57:13.862223 0.00% [DEBUG] switch_nat.c:170 Checking for PMP 4/5
2022-11-16 09:57:14.862506 0.00% [DEBUG] switch_nat.c:170 Checking for PMP 5/5
2022-11-16 09:57:15.862637 0.00% [ERR] switch_nat.c:199 Error checking for PMP [general error]
2022-11-16 09:57:15.862708 0.00% [DEBUG] switch_nat.c:422 Checking for UPnP
2022-11-16 09:57:27.863358 0.00% [INFO] switch_nat.c:438 No PMP or UPnP NAT devices detected!
2022-11-16 09:57:27.869274 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_scheduler.c:186 Starting task thread
2022-11-16 09:57:27.876233 0.00% [DEBUG] switch_rtp.c:1584 SRTP (srtp 2.4.0) initialized.
2022-11-16 09:57:27.876326 0.00% [DEBUG] switch_scheduler.c:263 Added task 1 heartbeat (core) to run at 1668572847
2022-11-16 09:57:27.876400 0.00% [DEBUG] switch_scheduler.c:263 Added task 2 check_ip (core) to run at 1668572847
2022-11-16 09:57:27.877037 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_core.c:1481 Created ip list rfc6598.auto default (deny)
2022-11-16 09:57:27.877093 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_utils.c:667 Adding 100.64.0.0/10 (allow) [] to list rfc6598.auto
2022-11-16 09:57:27.877121 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_core.c:1487 Created ip list rfc1918.auto default (deny)
2022-11-16 09:57:27.877145 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_utils.c:667 Adding 10.0.0.0/8 (allow) [] to list rfc1918.auto
2022-11-16 09:57:27.877169 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_utils.c:667 Adding 172.16.0.0/12 (allow) [] to list rfc1918.auto
2022-11-16 09:57:27.877200 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_utils.c:667 Adding 192.168.0.0/16 (allow) [] to list rfc1918.auto
2022-11-16 09:57:27.877225 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_utils.c:667 Adding fe80::/10 (allow) [] to list rfc1918.auto
2022-11-16 09:57:27.877248 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_core.c:1496 Created ip list wan.auto default (allow)
2022-11-16 09:57:27.877272 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_utils.c:667 Adding 0.0.0.0/8 (deny) [] to list wan.auto
2022-11-16 09:57:27.877295 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_utils.c:667 Adding 10.0.0.0/8 (deny) [] to list wan.auto
2022-11-16 09:57:27.877318 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_utils.c:667 Adding 172.16.0.0/12 (deny) [] to list wan.auto
2022-11-16 09:57:27.877341 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_utils.c:667 Adding 192.168.0.0/16 (deny) [] to list wan.auto
2022-11-16 09:57:27.877364 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_utils.c:667 Adding 169.254.0.0/16 (deny) [] to list wan.auto
2022-11-16 09:57:27.877387 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_utils.c:667 Adding 100.64.0.0/10 (deny) [] to list wan.auto
2022-11-16 09:57:27.877409 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_utils.c:667 Adding fe80::/10 (deny) [] to list wan.auto
2022-11-16 09:57:27.877432 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_core.c:1508 Created ip list wan_v6.auto default (allow)
2022-11-16 09:57:27.877455 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_utils.c:667 Adding 0.0.0.0/0 (deny) [] to list wan_v6.auto
2022-11-16 09:57:27.877478 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_utils.c:667 Adding fe80::/10 (deny) [] to list wan_v6.auto
2022-11-16 09:57:27.877502 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_core.c:1516 Created ip list wan_v4.auto default (allow)
2022-11-16 09:57:27.877527 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_utils.c:667 Adding 0.0.0.0/8 (deny) [] to list wan_v4.auto
2022-11-16 09:57:27.877550 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_utils.c:667 Adding 10.0.0.0/8 (deny) [] to list wan_v4.auto
2022-11-16 09:57:27.877573 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_utils.c:667 Adding 172.16.0.0/12 (deny) [] to list wan_v4.auto
2022-11-16 09:57:27.877592 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_utils.c:667 Adding 192.168.0.0/16 (deny) [] to list wan_v4.auto
2022-11-16 09:57:27.877615 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_utils.c:667 Adding 169.254.0.0/16 (deny) [] to list wan_v4.auto
2022-11-16 09:57:27.877640 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_utils.c:667 Adding 100.64.0.0/10 (deny) [] to list wan_v4.auto
2022-11-16 09:57:27.877665 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_utils.c:667 Adding ::/0 (deny) [] to list wan_v4.auto
2022-11-16 09:57:27.877688 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_core.c:1529 Created ip list any_v6.auto default (allow)
2022-11-16 09:57:27.877708 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_utils.c:667 Adding 0.0.0.0/0 (deny) [] to list any_v6.auto
2022-11-16 09:57:27.877731 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_core.c:1536 Created ip list any_v4.auto default (allow)
2022-11-16 09:57:27.877767 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_utils.c:667 Adding ::/0 (deny) [] to list any_v4.auto
2022-11-16 09:57:27.877781 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_core.c:1543 Created ip list nat.auto default (deny)
2022-11-16 09:57:27.877803 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_core.c:1545 Adding 10.0.0.199/255.255.252.0 (deny) to list nat.auto
2022-11-16 09:57:27.877826 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_utils.c:667 Adding 10.0.0.0/8 (allow) [] to list nat.auto
2022-11-16 09:57:27.877843 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_utils.c:667 Adding 172.16.0.0/12 (allow) [] to list nat.auto
2022-11-16 09:57:27.877866 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_utils.c:667 Adding 192.168.0.0/16 (allow) [] to list nat.auto
2022-11-16 09:57:27.877893 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_utils.c:667 Adding 100.64.0.0/10 (allow) [] to list nat.auto
2022-11-16 09:57:27.877916 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_core.c:1555 Created ip list loopback.auto default (deny)
2022-11-16 09:57:27.877939 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_utils.c:667 Adding 127.0.0.0/8 (allow) [] to list loopback.auto
2022-11-16 09:57:27.877970 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_utils.c:667 Adding ::1/128 (allow) [] to list loopback.auto
2022-11-16 09:57:27.877994 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_core.c:1562 Created ip list localnet.auto default (deny)
2022-11-16 09:57:27.878015 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_core.c:1565 Adding 10.0.0.199/255.255.252.0 (allow) to list localnet.auto
2022-11-16 09:57:27.878046 0.00% [CONSOLE] switch_core.c:1592 Created ip list lan default (allow)
2022-11-16 09:57:27.878093 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_utils.c:667 Adding 127.0.0.1/32 (allow) [] to list lan
2022-11-16 09:57:27.878117 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_utils.c:667 Adding 10.130.218.147/32 (allow) [] to list lan
2022-11-16 09:57:27.878142 0.00% [CONSOLE] switch_core.c:1592 Created ip list deny_private_v6 default (allow)
2022-11-16 09:57:27.878175 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_utils.c:667 Adding 0.0.0.0/0 (deny) [] to list deny_private_v6
2022-11-16 09:57:27.878201 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_utils.c:667 Adding fe80::/10 (deny) [] to list deny_private_v6
2022-11-16 09:57:27.878226 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_utils.c:667 Adding fc00::/7 (deny) [] to list deny_private_v6
2022-11-16 09:57:27.878251 0.00% [CONSOLE] switch_core.c:1592 Created ip list domains default (allow)
2022-11-16 09:57:27.878367 0.00% [WARNING] switch_msrp.c:204 Open of msrp.conf failed
2022-11-16 09:57:27.878394 0.00% [CONSOLE] switch_core.c:2518 Bringing up environment.
2022-11-16 09:57:27.878427 0.00% [CONSOLE] switch_core.c:2519 Loading Modules.
2022-11-16 09:57:27.879282 0.00% [INFO] switch_time.c:1430 Timezone loaded 1750 definitions
2022-11-16 09:57:27.879305 0.00% [CONSOLE] switch_time.c:1573 Clock calibration disabled.
2022-11-16 09:57:27.879320 0.00% [CONSOLE] switch_loadable_module.c:1768 Successfully Loaded [CORE_SOFTTIMER_MODULE]
2022-11-16 09:57:27.879341 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:301 Adding Timer 'soft'
2022-11-16 09:57:27.879429 0.00% [CONSOLE] switch_loadable_module.c:1768 Successfully Loaded [CORE_PCM_MODULE]
2022-11-16 09:57:27.879456 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:229 Adding Codec PROXY-VID 31 PROXY VIDEO PASS-THROUGH 90000hz 0ms 1ch (VBR)
2022-11-16 09:57:27.879478 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:229 Adding Codec PROXY 0 PROXY PASS-THROUGH 8000hz 20ms 2ch (VBR)
2022-11-16 09:57:27.879491 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:229 Adding Codec PROXY 0 PROXY PASS-THROUGH 8000hz 20ms 1ch (VBR)
2022-11-16 09:57:27.879507 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 11025hz 32ms 2ch 352800bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.879517 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 11025hz 32ms 1ch 176400bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.879523 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 11025hz 40ms 2ch 352800bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.879535 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 11025hz 40ms 1ch 176400bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.879541 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 22050hz 20ms 2ch 705600bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.879552 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 22050hz 20ms 1ch 352800bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.879563 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 44100hz 30ms 2ch 705600bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.879574 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 44100hz 30ms 1ch 705600bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.879585 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 44100hz 20ms 2ch 705600bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.879592 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 44100hz 20ms 1ch 705600bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.879600 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 44100hz 10ms 2ch 705600bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.879606 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 44100hz 10ms 1ch 705600bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.879614 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 48000hz 40ms 2ch 1536000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.879620 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 48000hz 40ms 1ch 768000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.879632 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 48000hz 30ms 2ch 1536000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.879641 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 48000hz 30ms 1ch 768000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.879650 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 48000hz 20ms 2ch 1536000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.879660 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 48000hz 20ms 1ch 768000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.879667 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 32000hz 8ms 2ch 1024000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.879675 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 32000hz 8ms 1ch 512000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.879687 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 32000hz 6ms 2ch 1024000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.879694 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 32000hz 6ms 1ch 512000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.879703 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 32000hz 4ms 2ch 1024000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.879709 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 32000hz 4ms 1ch 512000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.879721 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 32000hz 2ms 2ch 1024000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.879733 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 32000hz 2ms 1ch 512000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.879741 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 16000hz 8ms 2ch 512000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.879749 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 16000hz 8ms 1ch 256000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.879761 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 16000hz 6ms 2ch 512000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.879771 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 16000hz 6ms 1ch 256000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.879780 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 16000hz 4ms 2ch 512000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.879790 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 16000hz 4ms 1ch 256000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.879802 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 16000hz 2ms 2ch 512000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.879813 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 16000hz 2ms 1ch 256000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.879822 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 8000hz 8ms 2ch 256000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.879832 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 8000hz 8ms 1ch 128000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.879845 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 8000hz 6ms 2ch 256000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.879855 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 8000hz 6ms 1ch 128000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.879865 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 8000hz 4ms 2ch 256000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.879876 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 8000hz 4ms 1ch 128000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.879889 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 8000hz 2ms 2ch 256000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.879899 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 8000hz 2ms 1ch 128000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.879907 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 48000hz 10ms 2ch 1536000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.879915 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 48000hz 10ms 1ch 768000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.879921 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 48000hz 8ms 2ch 1536000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.879929 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 48000hz 8ms 1ch 768000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.879941 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 48000hz 6ms 2ch 1536000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.879947 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 48000hz 6ms 1ch 768000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.879957 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 48000hz 4ms 2ch 1536000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.879963 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 48000hz 4ms 1ch 768000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.879979 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 48000hz 2ms 2ch 1536000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.879986 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 48000hz 2ms 1ch 768000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.879992 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 24000hz 60ms 2ch 768000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.880002 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 24000hz 60ms 1ch 384000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.880008 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 24000hz 40ms 2ch 768000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.880020 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 24000hz 40ms 1ch 384000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.880026 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 24000hz 20ms 2ch 768000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.880037 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 24000hz 20ms 1ch 384000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.880043 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 12000hz 100ms 2ch 384000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.880054 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 12000hz 100ms 1ch 192000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.880066 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 12000hz 80ms 2ch 384000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.880074 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 12000hz 80ms 1ch 192000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.880081 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 12000hz 60ms 2ch 384000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.880087 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 12000hz 60ms 1ch 192000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.880101 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 12000hz 40ms 2ch 384000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.880111 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 12000hz 40ms 1ch 192000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.880122 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 12000hz 20ms 2ch 384000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.880135 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 12000hz 20ms 1ch 192000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.880140 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 32000hz 10ms 2ch 512000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.880155 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 32000hz 10ms 1ch 512000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.880164 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 32000hz 20ms 2ch 512000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.880176 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 32000hz 20ms 1ch 512000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.880182 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 32000hz 30ms 2ch 512000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.880192 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 32000hz 30ms 1ch 512000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.880197 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 32000hz 40ms 2ch 512000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.880207 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 32000hz 40ms 1ch 512000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.880213 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 32000hz 50ms 2ch 512000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.880225 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 32000hz 50ms 1ch 512000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.880234 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 32000hz 60ms 2ch 512000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.880242 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 32000hz 60ms 1ch 512000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.880253 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 16000hz 10ms 2ch 256000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.880260 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 16000hz 10ms 1ch 256000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.880268 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 16000hz 20ms 2ch 256000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.880280 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 16000hz 20ms 1ch 256000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.880287 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 16000hz 30ms 2ch 256000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.880298 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 16000hz 30ms 1ch 256000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.880304 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 16000hz 40ms 2ch 256000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.880316 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 16000hz 40ms 1ch 256000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.880328 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 16000hz 50ms 2ch 256000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.880337 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 16000hz 50ms 1ch 256000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.880346 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 16000hz 60ms 2ch 256000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.880356 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 16000hz 60ms 1ch 256000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.880362 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 8000hz 10ms 2ch 128000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.880566 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 8000hz 110ms 1ch 128000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.880578 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 8000hz 120ms 2ch 128000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.880587 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec L16 100 RAW Signed Linear (16 bit) 8000hz 120ms 1ch 128000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.880605 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec PCMU 0 G.711 ulaw 48000hz 10ms 2ch 768000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.880617 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec PCMU 0 G.711 ulaw 48000hz 10ms 1ch 384000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.880623 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec PCMU 0 G.711 ulaw 48000hz 40ms 1ch 384000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.880711 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec PCMU 0 G.711 ulaw 8000hz 40ms 1ch 64000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.880722 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec PCMU 0 G.711 ulaw 8000hz 50ms 1ch 64000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.880732 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec PCMU 0 G.711 ulaw 8000hz 60ms 1ch 64000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.880743 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec PCMU 0 G.711 ulaw 8000hz 70ms 1ch 64000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.880753 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec PCMU 0 G.711 ulaw 8000hz 80ms 1ch 64000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.880764 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec PCMU 0 G.711 ulaw 8000hz 90ms 1ch 64000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.880773 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec PCMU 0 G.711 ulaw 8000hz 100ms 1ch 64000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.880784 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec PCMU 0 G.711 ulaw 8000hz 110ms 1ch 64000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.880794 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec PCMU 0 G.711 ulaw 8000hz 120ms 1ch 64000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.880813 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec PCMA 8 G.711 alaw 8000hz 10ms 1ch 64000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.880826 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec PCMA 8 G.711 alaw 8000hz 20ms 1ch 64000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.880832 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec PCMA 8 G.711 alaw 8000hz 30ms 1ch 64000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.880844 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec PCMA 8 G.711 alaw 8000hz 40ms 1ch 64000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.880850 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec PCMA 8 G.711 alaw 8000hz 50ms 1ch 64000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.880861 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec PCMA 8 G.711 alaw 8000hz 60ms 1ch 64000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.880867 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec PCMA 8 G.711 alaw 8000hz 70ms 1ch 64000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.880876 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec PCMA 8 G.711 alaw 8000hz 80ms 1ch 64000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.880882 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec PCMA 8 G.711 alaw 8000hz 90ms 1ch 64000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.880893 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec PCMA 8 G.711 alaw 8000hz 100ms 1ch 64000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.880899 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec PCMA 8 G.711 alaw 8000hz 110ms 1ch 64000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.880912 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec PCMA 8 G.711 alaw 8000hz 120ms 1ch 64000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.880943 0.00% [CONSOLE] switch_loadable_module.c:1768 Successfully Loaded [CORE_SPEEX_MODULE]
2022-11-16 09:57:27.880967 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec SPEEX 99 Speex 32000hz 20ms 1ch 44000bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.880979 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec SPEEX 99 Speex 16000hz 20ms 1ch 42200bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.880985 0.00% [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:223 Adding Codec SPEEX 99 Speex 8000hz 20ms 1ch 24600bps
2022-11-16 09:57:27.881005 0.00% [CONSOLE] switch_loadable_module.c:2191 open of pre_load_modules.conf failed
2022-11-16 09:57:27.881292 0.00% [ERR] switch_core_db.c:106 SQL ERR [file is not a database]
2022-11-16 09:57:27.881313 0.00% [ERR] switch_core_db.c:241 SQL ERR [file is not a database]
2022-11-16 09:57:27.881341 0.00% [CRIT] switch_core_sqldb.c:645 Failure to connect to CORE_DB /dev/shm/core.db!
2022-11-16 09:57:27.881354 0.00% [ERR] switch_core_sqldb.c:3579 Error Opening DB!
2022-11-16 09:57:27.881359 0.00% [CRIT] switch_core_sqldb.c:3586 CORE DATABASE INITIALIZATION FAILURE! CHECK `core-db-dsn`!
2022-11-16 09:57:27.881371 0.00% [CRIT] switch_loadable_module.c:2196 Loading modules interrupted. [Error: Error activating database]
2022-11-16 09:57:27.881380 0.00% [CONSOLE] switch_core.c:2522 Error: Cannot load modules
```

- The output of `**$systemctl status freeswitch.service**` is as per below:

```
Job for freeswitch.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status freeswitch.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
root@Resumex:/opt/freeswitch/bin# systemctl status freeswitch.service
● freeswitch.service - freeswitch
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/freeswitch.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2022-11-16 11:02:31 IST; 11s ago
  Process: 7949 ExecStart=/opt/freeswitch/bin/freeswitch -u freeswitch -g daemon -ncwait $DAEMON_OPTS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 20724 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Nov 16 11:02:31 Resumex systemd[1]: freeswitch.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Nov 16 11:02:31 Resumex systemd[1]: freeswitch.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Nov 16 11:02:31 Resumex systemd[1]: Stopped freeswitch.
Nov 16 11:02:31 Resumex systemd[1]: freeswitch.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Nov 16 11:02:31 Resumex systemd[1]: freeswitch.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 16 11:02:31 Resumex systemd[1]: Failed to start freeswitch.
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you can see what the error is just from the log you posted here, the cause is that something wrong with your db file.

Please check

1. if the file exists
2. if the file is corrupted
3. if the file owns the proper permissions.

> 2022-11-16 09:57:27.881292 0.00% [ERR] switch_core_db.c:106 SQL ERR [file is not a database]

> 2022-11-16 09:57:27.881313 0.00% [ERR] switch_core_db.c:241 SQL ERR [file is not a database]

> 2022-11-16 09:57:27.881341 0.00% [CRIT] switch_core_sqldb.c:645 Failure to connect to CORE_DB /dev/shm/core.db!

> 2022-11-16 09:57:27.881354 0.00% [ERR] switch_core_sqldb.c:3579 Error Opening DB!
> 2022-11-16 09:57:27.881359 0.00% [CRIT] switch_core_sqldb.c:3586 CORE DATABASE INITIALIZATION FAILURE! CHECK `core-db-dsn`!

> 2022-11-16 09:57:27.881371 0.00% [CRIT] switch_loadable_module.c:2196 Loading modules interrupted. [Error: Error activating database]

Comment: Thanks @Chris for the reply! Coming to your above answer "the cause is that something wrong with your db file." - I have already deleted the DB files. FreeSWITCH should generate the new files on restart. But I'm getting error while restarting FreeSWITCH.

Comment: Hey, I have found the solution. I just deleted the core.db file located at /dev/shm/ and restarted FreeSWITCH.